# No intellisense or suggestsions for the python igraph `Vertex` class

Tags: python, intellisense, igraph, pylance

I've noticed that while working on my project that the `igraph.Vertex` class doesn't have any intellisense. I didn't mind at first but it has become annoying now that I'm using it more in some parts of the project. It looks like Pylance isn't really detecting the class but the [documentation](https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.Vertex.html) suggests it's meant to be used because it isn't a private class. The only thing that appears in intellisense are the default/built-in methods. Moreover, when I actually run the code itself everything is fine and the methods execute normally! I'm not sure if this is a Pylance issue or an igraph one.

[no intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmDc.png)

I was expecting everything to go just fine with Pylance detecting it, so I think it's a Pylance issue. I couldn't find similar issues which is why I'm making this post.

Comment: The vertex class of igraph is from a C extension, which is why I'm guessing it does not have types from pylance.

Comment: This is a known problem and there are plans to improve it in the long term. https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/450#issuecomment-953695608 You can add your vote to that issue.